# How to set the focus on Bootstrap carousel to make keyboard buttons working on angular?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have a list of images and I have loaded them in ngb-carousel component Bootstrap, it works fine.

I have div which when clicked opens a modal div and inside it I have my carousel. I would like the user to immediately be able to use the keyboard arrows and not have to click the arrows on the screen to enable the keyboard arrows to work.

I have tried using ViewChild on ngb-carousel to set the focus but no luck getting it to work thus far.

```
  <ngb-carousel #sliderRef ...  </ngb-carousel>

  @ViewChild('sliderRef', {static : true}) sliderReference: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log(this.sliderReference);
      console.log('after view init');
      this.sliderReference.nativeElement.focus();
  }
```

but it throws error ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there an *ngIf wrapping your carousel? Or any other reason that component might not have loaded by the time ngAfterViewInit() runs?

Comment: on  ngb-carousel component no it doesn't have ngIf